# How do I load my data from wire before executing renderedCallback?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lifecycle

I am trying to send an object, accountFields (comes from the wire method), to a method, makeTree, which is called in a renderedCallback. The makeTree renders a tree hierarchy ui component. A conditional keeps the renderedCallback from running again after it has been initialized so the ui doesn't keep populating. But the accountFields object is undefined when passed into the makeTree method. What can I do to pass the populated object into that method successfully? Thanks!

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {  loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name'
import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/d3';

export default class RelationshipMap extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
accountIcon = D3 + '/account_120.png';
account;
d3Initialized = false;
accountFields;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD]})
account({error, data}){
    if(data){
        this.account = data;
        this.accountFields = this.account.fields;
        //console.log(this.accountFields);
    }
};

get accountUrl() {
    return (this.sfdcBaseUrl = window.location.origin + "/" + this.recordId);
}

get accountName() {
    return this.account ? getFieldValue(this.account, ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD) : '';
}

renderedCallback() {
    if(this.d3Initialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.d3Initialized = true;

    loadScript(this, D3 + '/d3.min.js').then(() => {
        const div = this.template.querySelector('.d3');
        this.makeTree(div);
    })
    .catch(error => window.console.log(error));
}

makeTree(div){
    console.log(this.accountFields);
    var treeData ={
        "name": "Durango Holding",
        "children": [
            { "name": "Lacy Durango",
              "children" : [
                  {"name" : "Joint Consumer Checking Account"},
                  {"name" : "Savings Account"},
                  {"name" : "Greg Durango",
                    "children" : [
                        {"name" : "Auto Loan"}
                    ]}
              ]
            },
            { "name": "Durango Trucking" },
            { "name": "Durango Leasing",
              "children" : [
                  { "name" : "TEF"}
              ] 
            }
         ]
       };
    console.log(treeData);

    var rectHeight = 230;
    var rectWidth = 340;
    
    //setting the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {top: 20, right:30, bottom:30, left:2};
    var width = 2200 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 1250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    //Declare a tree Layout and assign its size
    var treemap = d3.tree()
            .size([width, height]);
    
    //Assigns the data to hierarchy using parent-child relationships
    var nodes = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d){
                    return d.children;
                });
    console.log(nodes);
    
    //NOTE: This assigns a range of properties to each node including (node.data, node.depth, node.height, node.parent, node.children)
    //We are telling the function to use the "children" element from treeData to generate property of the nodes. 
    
    //Map the node data to tree Layout
    nodes = treemap(nodes);
    console.log(nodes);
    

    //Append the Map(SVG) to the body of the Lightning Component
    var svg = d3.select(div)  
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right  )
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 200)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Add All Links between nodes
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1)) //We are not including the main 'root' node as since its drawn from child to parent.
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("fill", "none") //Including all the styles directly here as the Style configured is not applied to lighting component.
            .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
            .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
            .attr("d", function(d){  //Here Attribute 'd' is used to describe the curve. Using Bezier Curve
                return "M" + (d.x + (rectWidth / 2)) + "," + d.y
                    + "L" + (d.x + (rectWidth / 2))  + "," + ((d.y + d.parent.y) / 1.69)
                    + " " + (d.parent.x  + (rectWidth / 2)) + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 1.69
                    + " " + (d.parent.x  + (rectWidth / 2)) + "," + (d.parent.y + rectHeight)
            });
    console.log(nodes.descendants());
    console.log(nodes.descendants().slice(1));
    
    //Add Each Node as a Group - Ie, setting up a group
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes.descendants())
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node node--leaf")
                    .attr("transform", function(d){
                            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                    });

var icon = '<div class="slds-media__figure">' +
           '<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon slds-icon-standard-groups" aria-hidden="true">' +
           '<img src={accIcon}alt="">' + '</span>' + '</div>';

    node.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 350)
    .attr("height", 280)
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("class","box")
    .html(function(d) {
        return '<div class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-heading_medium slds-p-around_x-small">Related Accounts</div><br>' +
         '<div class="slds-p-around_small"" style="width:320px">' +
        '<ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space" style="background-color: white;">' +
        '<li class="slds-item">' +
        '<article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">' + 
        icon +
        '<h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title="Anypoint Connectors">' +
        '<a href="#">' + d.data.name + '</a>' + '</h3>' +'<div class="slds-tile__detail">' +
        '<p class="slds-text-heading_medium">$500,000</p>' +
        '<p class="slds-truncate" title="Company One">' +
        '<a href="#">Company One</a>' +'</p>' + 
        '<p class="slds-truncate" title="Closing 9/30/2015">Closing 9/30/2015</p>' +
        '</div>' +'</article>' +'</li>' +'</ul>' + '</div>';;
    });
    //.html('<div class="slds-text-heading_large">Durango Trucks</div>');
    

    //Add Text to the node
    node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x",48)
    .attr("y", function(d){ return d.children ? 20 : 20;})
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {return d.data.Name; });


}
}
```

html

```
<template>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;margin-left:15px;">
        <a href={accountUrl}>Back to {accountName}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d3" lwc:dom="manual">
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <span class="slds-icon_container" title="description of icon when needed">
          <div class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-groups" aria-hidden="true">
            <img src={accountIcon}></img>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `makeTree` function of your component entirely depends on the data, you either need to load `d3.min.js` after your data has arrived or even better you can load the js the you're doing already, just move the initialize logic to somewhere(wire) to be called when data is available. This is the pattern we usually use,

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ ...fields ] })
wiredRecord({ error, data }){
    if(error){
     //.. handle errors
    } else if(data){
        // your data is available you can initialize
        this.initialize();
    }
}

isInitialized = !1;
async renderedCallback(){
    // use renderedCallback hook to load your script only
    if(!this.isInitialized){
        await loadScript(this, D3).catch(err => console.error(err));
        this.isInitialized = !0;
    }
}
initialize(){
     const d3El = this.template.querySelector('.d3');
     //...process here
     this.makeTree(d3El);
}
```

This way you'll load the js only once & call `makeTree` only when data updates.

Comment: Thank you this is good information!